# How to manage "NO-BREAK SPACE" used for formatting of XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, utf-8, xsd

Some users are trying to upload a document with `U+00A0` `NO-BREAK SPACE` symbols used for formatting:

```
<myConfig>
  <defaultConfig>
    <defaultTitle>Hello!</defaultTitle>
  </defaultConfig>
</myConfig>
```

I understand that according to a spec, it may be invalid XML, but if some bad editor or web-page where this data is copy-pasted from gives this nasty text, I need to support it, or print a good error message.

Currently, I'm doing

```
XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xmlFromUser);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(xsdSchemaText, XmlNodeType.Document, null);
XmlSchema xmlSchema = XmlSchema.Read(xmlReader, null);
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
schemas.Add(xmlSchema);              
d.Validate(schemas, (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    // process errors here
    //Console.WriteLine($"[{eventArgs.Severity}] {eventArgs.Message}");
});
```

Which gives me a lot of these errors:

```
[Error] The element 'myConfig' cannot contain text. List of possible elements expected: 'defaultConfig'.
```

For real-world inputs, it produces one error for each block with `NO-BREAK SPACE`, which make user think the system is broken. There's no way how the normal user can detect and fix this kind of issues with the document.

That's why I need to **ignore** this characters, convert them to normal spaces, or do anything else what will make the above XML valid. But it's a large system, and I don't want to affect anything in existing values (e.g. it is OK for `defaultTitle` to contain those weird spaces), so plain-text processing (even with clever Regexes) is not an option.

Comment: Are you  just failing the schema check or failing the parsing?  You do not need to do the schema check if you can parse the file.  My belief is schema checking should be done when the xml is created.  When reading you can ignore the schema check and only produce error messages when the code doesn't run.  I know there will be problems using this philosophy. Suppose you had a program that read medical data on a patient and you were missing a required patient zip code when reading the file.Isn't it better to read the xml and then let an operator enter zip code than reject and send back to doctor?

Comment: I'm failing during schema check. I have to leave this check, because it actually helps user in other cases, like missing required attributes, etc. May be I can postpone this check in some cases, but even checking this idea for every possible XML I'm supporting is too much. Schema validation should stay.

Comment: Is the first line of the XML UTF-8?  Try deleting first line and see what happens.  The error may be due to a conflict with the Ident in the xml and the data inside the file.  What I sometimes do is use StingReader to skip first line.  XDocument does not need the Ident line : StringReader reader = new StringReader(xmlFromUser); reader.ReadLine(); XDocument d = XDocument.Load(reader);

Comment: You mean XML declaration line? No, the input doesn't contain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML containing [`U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) characters is perfectly well-formed.  Your problem is that, according to the [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fourth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-20060816/#sec-common-syn), which is the XML standard supported by `XmlReader`, `U+00A0` is *not considered a whitespace character*:

> White Space
>
> [3]`S      ::=      (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+`

(This contrasts with the definition of whitespace by the [Unicode consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) which does include `U+00A0`.)

Thus when `<myConfig>` is loaded it is interpreted as having *mixed content* including text other than insignificant whitespace, which in turn causes causes an error to be thrown when validating `<myConfig>` against your schema (not shown) because the element is, presumably not allowed to have a textual value by the schema.

One way to prevent the error would be to create a custom `XmlReader` that translates `U+00A0` to, say, a regular space character:

```
public class XmlNoBreakSpaceTextReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public XmlNoBreakSpaceTextReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    string overrideValue = null;
    XmlNodeType? overrideType = null;

    public override string Value { get { return overrideValue ?? base.Value; } }

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType { get { return overrideType ?? base.NodeType; } }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        overrideValue = null;
        overrideType = null;
        while (base.Read())
        {
            var nodeType = base.NodeType;
            if (nodeType == XmlNodeType.Text)
            {
                var value = base.Value;
                // Maybe check here that string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) and only replace nonbreaking spaces in whitespace strings?
                var newValue = value.Replace('\u00A0', ' ');
                if ((object)newValue != (object)value)
                {
                    var newNodeType = newValue.All(c => XmlConvert.IsWhitespaceChar(c)) ? XmlNodeType.Whitespace : nodeType;
                    if (newNodeType == XmlNodeType.Whitespace && WhitespaceHandling != WhitespaceHandling.All)
                        continue;
                    overrideValue = newValue;
                    overrideType = newNodeType;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
XDocument d;
using (var textReader = new StringReader(xmlFromUser))
using (var reader = new XmlNoBreakSpaceTextReader(textReader))
{
    d = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

Note however than `XmlTextReader` is deprecated according to its [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, we recommend that you create [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=netframework-4.8) instances by using the [XmlReader.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=netframework-4.8) method to take advantage of new functionality.

Thus you may want to create an `XmlReader` [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as shown [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWrappingReader.cs) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2abc1zd(v=vs.71).aspx) (under *Chaining XmlReaders*) then subclass the decorator and fix the text values there.  While a bit more work this approach may be more robust.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqECkH).